# What's the best way to monitor a file for changes and update a collection with new data from the file?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor project that runs a python script once a day to query an API and save the results to a JSON file in `private`. The meteor server watches that JSON file for changes. When the file changes, the server reads and parses the file and updates a collection accordingly.

The problem is that the assets in `private` are loaded at meteor startup and copied into a different asset folder as read-only, and thus the script can't make changes to the file.

I could maybe change the permissions on that asset destination folder but that seems hacky. I don't think assets in `private` are intended to be dynamic, anyways. Anybody know how I can accomplish this flow?

- Meteor server kicks off python script once per day
- Script queries API, saves results to JSON file on server
- Meteor server reads JSON file and updates collection

Comment: Are you running your Meteor application using `meteor` on a production  server?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I haven't deployed it yet, currently it's just running on a development server.

Comment: @Jankapunkt to clarify I run with `meteor --once` to disable the hot code push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

Instead of having the meteor app kick off the python script daily, I just put the python script on the host's file system (outside of the meteor app bundle) and created a cron job on the host to run it daily. The JSON output file was saved to the host's file system.

Then, in my meteor app, I created a file watch on the output JSON that triggered a file read.

I was running into some issues with Meteor Up (mup), so see my other answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443065/how-do-i-read-a-file-from-the-local-file-system-from-inside-a-meteor-app).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution may be for the Python script to write its JSON to a Mongo database. Then Meteor can automatically subscribe to any changes made to that collection.

Comment: I would suggest this also from a deployment perspective, since some day @Sam might want to run the deployment which will not have the Meteor development environment's out-of-the-box file state observer feature. And FS handling on a production server can become quite messy easily (sync/async/permissions/processes/locks/hazards etc).