# How do I read a file from the local file system from inside a meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app that needs to periodically read a file located on the host's file system, outside of the app package. I am using node's `fs` to accomplish this, and it works fine on my (macOS) development machine.

However, when I run `mup deploy` to deploy it to my (Ubuntu 14) server, mup returns the following error after starting meteor:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/sam/data/all_data.json'
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:652:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:553:33)`

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: "on the host's file system": what do you mean by "host"?

Comment: @ghybs By that I mean the file system of the server (in this case, a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 14) that is running the deployed meteor app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should follow mup documentation closely. Have you seen volumes setup in mup config? Try this to solve your issue.

Reason: mup runs app in docker without any access to host file system unless specified. Volumes setup does this for you with mup deployment.

Below is the part of mup config from http://meteor-up.com/docs.html, Everything Configured, read more to get a better idea.

```
    name: 'app',
    path: '../app',

    // lets you add docker volumes (optional). Can be used to
    // store files between app deploys and restarts.
    volumes: {
      // passed as '-v /host/path:/container/path' to the docker run command
      '/host/path': '/container/path',
      '/second/host/path': '/second/container/path'
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The user you have that is running your meteor build on the server needs to have access to that folder - read access. I would store the file in a different directory than the home one, because you don't want to mess it up. Either way doing something like `chmod -R 444 /home/sam/data` should give read access to any user for all files in that directory. You are probably running `meteor` as your local user(`sam`?) in development mode on your macOS, but the built up gets run as `meteor` or some other user on ubuntu, because of `mup` and `forever`.

Comment: According to my mup config, `mup` is deploying on the server using root. That should give mup (and I assume meteor as well) sufficient access to read files in /home/sam, right?

Comment: That is not correct, you should look at the node process running for your meteor build - it would be something different than root in most cases. AFAIK running meteor as `root` is not recommended as well. Also depending on the permissions of your home folder, root might not be able to read from there.

Comment: I did a `ps aux` and it shows node as root: 
`root      2585  1.0  7.4 1213152 75200 ?       Sl   06:16   1:00 node main.js`

Going to try to change permissions anyways and see if it helps

Comment: You should try doing `top` instead and then press `z` then `x` then use `shift + ,` and `shift + .` to move around columns and sort by `%CPU` or `%MEM` you might have multiple node processes. But yeah, just try out the permissions thing or move the file and try reading it again.